# current location is not loading at Startup

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

when i run the application it load the map but not my current location.when i clicked on gps after then it zoom in to my current location. i also want to update the location as the user moves from one location to another. this location update code is not working properly. And when i change the orientation of device it reload the map again.Same things happens again.

Xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

class file

```
         package com.design.googlemap;

            import android.location.Criteria;
            import android.location.Location;
            import android.location.LocationListener;
            import android.location.LocationManager;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

            public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
                private GoogleMap googlemap;
                private LocationManager locationManager;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    SetMapIfNeeded();   
                        }

                private void SetMapIfNeeded() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(googlemap==null){
                        //try to obtain google map form SupportMapFragment;
                        googlemap=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                        if(googlemap!= null){
                            SetUpMap();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private void SetUpMap() {
                    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
                    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                    // Get LocationManager object from System Service Location_SERVICE
                    locationManager =(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
                    Criteria criteria= new Criteria();

                    //Get the name of the best provider
                    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);

                    //Get Current Location
                    Location myLocation= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                    //Set map type
                    googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                    //Get Latitude object of current location
                    double latitude=myLocation.getLatitude();

                    //Get Latitude object of current location
                    double longitude=myLocation.getLatitude();

                    //Create a LatLng object for current location
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

                    //show the current location of Google Map
                    googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                    LocationListener listner = new LocationListener() {

                        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            locationManager =(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        }
                    };
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) listner);


                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

ManifestFile

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.design.googlemap"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="12"
                android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

            <permission
                android:name="com.design.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />

             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
            <!--
             The following two permissions are not required to use
             Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
            -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.design.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
            <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

                <activity
                    android:name="com.design.googlemap.MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                    android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

Comment: The map will be reloaded on orientation change.. [put this lines in ur manifest to avoid this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20607162/2591002)

Comment: Check this link..

[How to detect Location Provider ? GPS or Network Provider][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350665/how-to-detect-location-provider-gps-or-network-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Get the name of the best provider
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
```

Even if Gps if Off. Your approx location will be pointed.

And for locationUpdates on your GoogleMaps go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742551/how-to-get-my-location-changed-event-with-google-maps-android-api-v2)

Also for zooming to a particular position add this code:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(YOUR_LATLNG).zoom(ZOOM_LEVEL).build();     // int ZOOM_LEVEL=12            
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

go through this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views?hl=fr-FR#moving_the_camera) for more on zooming.

**To hide the WebView call the Visibility functions in your Activity[OnClick of your Button]**

```
WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_WEB_VIEW);
    wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);// when you want to hide[shrink]
    wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// when you want to Show[Zoom]
```

Comment: it is pointed to my current location but i want to show that when user open my app it automattically zoom in to dat pointed location

Comment: i have updated my answer. Hope this is what you want!

Comment: If my answer worked for you..then you can Up for my answer and close your question. Or else your question will be as unanswered

Comment: sir one more thing i added a button on map when user click on that button the map will shifted to the 3/4 portion of screen and rest portion is filled contain webview. if user click on map will zoom to certain level and same in webview case. sir for this should i have to declare map again or i can include previous one into next activity. please guide me how to do it.

Comment: This shrinking and Expanding can be done in the same Activity. I dont find any need to create any other activity. Just use animation and do the shrinking and Zooming. And YES YOU CAN USE THE SAME MAP VIEW AGAIN

Comment: i want to add webview but on startup i want only map and when user click on button then it shrink and map appear.how can i hide webview at startup.

Comment: Thanku very much sir :)

Answer (score 1):

### 1.

If you only want to show your own location, than a MyLocationOverlay is probably easiest.

Quick information here (rest of that article might be helpful too):

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#maps_mylocation

Use `MyLocationOverlay`, as that is what it is there for. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) that uses `MyLocationOverlay` and a custom overlay; you can always get rid of the custom one if you do not need it.

### 2.

To avoid the common behavior of reloading, you have to handle configuration change for your app .

Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml. This tells the system what configuration changes you are going to handle yourself - in this case by doing nothing.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Mam where in mainfest in <application> ??